# Trying to understand code for a called back function for wiki Viewer

Tags: javascript

1. What is the purpose of variable k in this function?
2. Is window[callback] an array?
3. If I try to print this line: window[callbackName] = k; it says undefined. Here is the link: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Search_and_discovery.

   ```
         var createCallback = function (k) {
         var i = 1;
         var callbackName;
         do {
           callbackName = 'callback' + i;
           i = i + 1;
         } while (window[callbackName])
         window[callbackName] = k;
         return callbackName;
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. k is a parameter where a function gets passed in (`window[callbackName] = k;` this code at least implicitly indicates this).
2. window[callback] is not an array, this is just other syntax for 
   `window.callback`. The result of this is that you dynamically select callbacks because the callback in `var callbackName;` can be different.
3. It says undefined because you need to put something into the parameter k. If you put something as a parameter it will return something and this will not be undefined.

Comment: `window[callback] is not an array, this is just other syntax for window.callback` it's actually a bit more - `callback` is a variable, so you can have it dynamic. E.g., if you set `callback = "foo"` then `window[callback]` will be exactly like calling `window.foo` and if you set it to `"bar"` then it will be like calling `window.bar`. So, basically it's changing - in this case it's adding a bunch unique callbacks to `window` by appending a counter to the callback name.